# invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x80\xff\xa8R\x02\x03GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin\

Tags: python-3.6, word2vec

**I use Python 3.6 and windows 10**

please help me out in solving this problem
I'm a beginner,explain briefly

**Error:**

```
data loaded!
number of sentences: 2467
vocab size: 30417
max sentence length: 2721
loading word2vec vectors...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2ecf35f5c4fb> in <module>
      8 print ('max sentence length: ' + str(max_l))
      9 print ('loading word2vec vectors...',)
---> 10 w2v = load_bin_vec(w2v_file, vocab)
     11 print ('word2vec loaded!')
     12 print ('num words already in word2vec: ' + str(len(w2v)))

<ipython-input-12-824546589dfe> in load_bin_vec(fname, vocab)
     49     with open(fname, "rb") as f:
     50         header = f.readline()
---> 51         vocab_size, layer1_size = map(int, header.split())
     52         binary_len =  np.dtype('float32').itemsize * layer1_size
     53         for line in range(vocab_size):

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x80\xff\xa8R\x02\x03GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin\x00L\x9d\x07\xbc\xce\xf5\xfb\xff\xad\x902#\xbb\x8cP\x19\x99\xc5\xb9\xefsTF\xd1\x92R\xd1DB\x11E\xa9\xbe'
```

how can i remove this error ?

Comment: Well, does `b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x80\xff\xa8R\x02\x03GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin\x00L\x9d\x07\xbc\xce\xf5\xfb\xff\xad\x902#\xbb\x8cP\x19\x99\xc5\xb9\xefsTF\xd1\x92R\xd1DB\x11E\xa9\xbe'` look like something which could be translated into an `int`??? You need to do some parsing on it (something more than just calling that `split()` as you do).

Comment: What's the source/format of the file involved? What code did you execute to trigger the error? What's the origin/source-code for the `load_bin_vec()` function?

Answer (score 1):

On line 49, You've read the file in `'rb'` mode. 
`'rb'` mode reads the data in binary format.

Replace `'rb'` with `'r'`